# Pandas: How can I fill in the n/a with the mean of previous none-empty value and next none-empty value

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have some N/A value in my dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,3],
              'B':[1,1,1,3],
              'C':[1,np.nan,3,5],
              'D':[2,np.nan, np.nan, 6]})
print(df)

    A   B   C   D
0   1   1   1.0 2.0
1   1   1   NaN NaN
2   1   1   3.0 NaN
3   3   3   5.0 6.0
```

How can I fill in the n/a value with the mean of its previous non-empty value and next non-empty value in its column?
For example, the second value in column C should be filled in with (1+3)/2= 2

Desired Output:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   1   1.0 2.0
1   1   1   2.0 4.0
2   1   1   3.0 4.0
3   3   3   5.0 6.0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ffill` and `bfill` for replace `NaN`s by forward and back filling, then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and `groupby` by index with aggregate `mean`:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df.ffill(), df.bfill()]).groupby(level=0).mean()
print (df1)
   A  B    C    D
0  1  1  1.0  2.0
1  1  1  2.0  4.0
2  1  1  3.0  4.0
3  3  3  5.0  6.0
```

Detail:

```
print (df.ffill())
   A  B    C    D
0  1  1  1.0  2.0
1  1  1  1.0  2.0
2  1  1  3.0  2.0
3  3  3  5.0  6.0

print (df.bfill())
   A  B    C    D
0  1  1  1.0  2.0
1  1  1  3.0  6.0
2  1  1  3.0  6.0
3  3  3  5.0  6.0
```